# Capture the longest leading whitespace substring from lines

Tags: code-golf, string, whitespace

#### The Challenge

Given a multiline string, return the longest substring of leading whitespace present in every line, ignoring empty lines or lines composed only of whitespace.  If input is empty or whitespace, return nullish or the empty string--up to you.

Update: Per [Meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095/53748), the input may also be treated as an array of strings.  My examples below could be shortened by excluding the `.split()` calls.

---

I wrote a quick script for my iPhone that comments or uncomments JavaScript code (since I can't use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>).

I want the `//`  placed the furthest right that it can, given that each `//`  is aligned with the other lines.  If a line is only whitespace (or empty), I want to skip adding a comment.

To do this, I must determine the longest leading whitespace substring that exists in every line.  So, given the input string

```
  const x = () =>
    y.split()
      .map(s =>
        s.length
      )
      .join()
    
  console.log(x)
```

the result of the algorithm would be 2 spaces.  (Note: Line 7 has 4 leading spaces, but the browser may or may not remove them.  It does not appear to remove them in the example solutions below.)  If the input was only lines 3-7, the result would be 6 spaces.

A simple JS solution to achieve this would be

```js
const solution = text => {
  const lines = text.split('\n').filter(l => !!l.trim())

  let result = ''
  while (lines.every(l => l.startsWith(result + ' '))) {
    result += ' '
  }

  return result
}

// test

const text = 
`  const x = () =>
    y.split()
      .map(s =>
        s.length
      )
      .join()

  console.log(x)`

let result = solution(text);
console.log(`|${result}| ${result.length} spaces`)

const lines3Through7 = text.split('\n').slice(2, 7).join('\n')

result = solution(lines3Through7)
console.log(`|${result}| ${result.length} spaces`)

result = solution(
`abc
  def`)
console.log(`|${result}| ${result.length} spaces`)
```

I'm sure you can do better than this.

Another would be

```js
const solution = text =>
  ' '.repeat(
    text.split('\n')
      .filter(l => !!l.trim())
      .map(l => l.length - l.trimStart().length)
      .reduce((m, v) => Math.min(m, v))
  )

// test

const text =
`  const x = () =>
    y.split()
      .map(s =>
        s.length
      )
      .join()
    
  console.log(x)`

let result = solution(text);
console.log(`|${result}| ${result.length} spaces`)

const lines3Through7 = text.split('\n').slice(2, 7).join('\n')

result = solution(lines3Through7)
console.log(`|${result}| ${result.length} spaces`)

result = solution(
`abc
  def`)
console.log(`|${result}| ${result.length} spaces`)
```

---

Assume all whitespaces are space characters (i.e. not `\t`).  For input that has no non-whitespace characters, it should return nullish or 0 spaces, up to you.

You can use any language<s>, but I'd also like *someone* to present an answer in JavaScript</s> ✅.

Shortest answer wins.  Include your answer, a prettified version of your answer for readability, and for esoteric languages, an explanation of how your script works.

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to contain at least one line which is neither empty nor composed only of whitespace?

Comment: Yes, that was supposed to read *lines 3-7, the result would be 6 spaces*.  And no, not guaranteed.

Comment: Can we assume the input only contains printable ASCII including spaces (and newlines)?

Comment: What should be the output for an input that consists of nothing but empty/whitespace-only lines?

Comment: @DLosc updated!  Return nullish or the empty string, up to you.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
=⁶Pi0’⁶ẋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/2UeO2gEyDRw0zgYyHu7r/P9y95XD7w537NCP//1dXV4/hUlBIzs8rLlGoULBV0NBUsLUDiigoVOoVF@RklmhognkKCnq5iQUaxTBZECjWy0nNSy/JgArAFWblZ@ZBtUHNzs9J1cvJT9eo0ARaqAO1lGxD4WYkJiVzKaSkpiEZSgufKOjr@6VWlCjkZOalAi3ILchJLUnNqVRIyknMy1YoycgsVijJzE1VSCzKL81L4cLrZxgG8gE)

-1 thanks to Jonathan Allan reminding me of meta consensus on being able to take a list of lines.

```
=⁶          For each character on each line, is it a space?
  P         Take the product along each column,
   i0       and find the first 1-index of 0 (or 0 if not found).
     ’      Decrement
      ⁶ẋ    and yield a space repeated that many times (or none if not positive).
```

`n⁶SÄ¬S⁶ẋ` works similarly, but does not ignore all-whitespace lines if there's nothing else.

If we can assume the input contains no codepoints under 32 other than newlines, this *almost* works:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
Ṁ»\f⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY8xDoJAEEV7TvE7IDFwAjyCvYkNwgCrwy5x1wQ6rbyQMSEkFnoSvMiKBo2VhYmTTDF/Zt7PXxFzY23f7i7dIrvtT7bvjtdD3579ubWu6y4cIFFSG9SI4PmIpoMCNIGuWBjPf05AUMaVp1/bR@mASeamGIX34UoJOb6NbMUUsMq92h8MJ6Ppz9A3I14mDlLKPqD/SIIwnFFtwELSYFBWTIa4wZJjuYYphIYRJSHeqK1Mna@ZXz3Mdw)

-1 because I tried replacing `»/` with `Ṁ` just in case that would work, and after further consideration, of course it would work--the lexicographically greatest line is precisely some line with the fewest leading spaces that has something else after them (under the assumption stated above).

-1 thanks to Jonathan Allan reminding me of meta consensus on being able to take a list of lines.

Fails to ignore all-whitespace lines if there's nothing else. A fix in fewer than 3 bytes seems unlikely (though `Ṁ»\ḟȧfɗ⁶` in 3 bytes seems worth mentioning).

```
Ỵ         Split on newlines.
 Ṁ        Take the lexicographically greatest row,
  »\      find the largest character in each of its prefixes,
    f⁶    and remove any that aren't spaces.
```

Comment: These do not deal with the edge case where all the lines in the input are space-only. As I read it such an input should yield an empty string.

Comment: Also, we can actually take a list of lines by [Meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095/53748).

Comment: What a horrible, horrible language.  Well done!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>10</s>  9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 by using the default ruling that [Submissions may use list of strings instead of multi-line strings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095/53748).

```
n⁶T€FṂ’⁶ẋ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lines (lists of characters) that yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/vUeO2kEdNa9we7mx61DATyHu4q/v/w91bDrc/3Lnv/391dfUYLgWF5Py84hKFCgVbBQ1NBVs7oIiCQqVecUFOZomGJpinoKCXm1igUQyTBYFivZzUvPSSDKgAXGFWfmYeVBvU7PycVL2c/HSNCk2ghQA)**

#### How?

```
n⁶T€FṂ’⁶ẋ - Link: list lists of characters, Lines
 ⁶        - space character
n         - not equals? (vectorises across all the characters in Lines)
   €      - for each:
  T       -   truthy indices (1-indexed)
    F     - flatten
     Ṃ    - minimum (minimum of the empty list is 0)
      ’   - decrement -> number of "common" leading spaces, N
       ⁶  - space character
        ẋ - repeat N times (repeating -1 or 0 times gives an empty list)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
εDðKk}ßð×
```

Input as a list of character-lists.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FaXwxu8s2sPzz@84fD0/48alikd3q/0PzpaSUFJB4yTgTgfiPOAuBiIS6DiFVDaFkprALEmkpidUqwOwhQYrgRiPahJBUCcA8SZUFMhJmDTBcMgnblAnAjVrQE1Cb@d6LgYahLI7lSoz9KhbsjAawJh12VBQysTai4uPyGLoIdwPpLbYO7Mh7pRAxryYDNjYwE) (footer is added to pretty-print the string of spaces) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@mFFCUWlJSqVtQlJlXkpqikJlXUFpipaCkU2nLpeSYXFKamIMQCz607dBC2//ntroc3uCdXXt4/uENh6f/V/IvLYEosHd51LBM6fB@Jft0JQWNw/sVigsSk1OLNZV0Dm2z/x@tpKCQnJ9XXKJQoWCroKGpYGsXk6cABJV6xQU5mSUamhCugoJebmKBRjFcHgSK9XJS89JLMmAiCLVZ@Zl5MK0gEmRFfk6qXk5@ukYF0GoFJQoNBRmRmJQM4qSkpoF4SrEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ε      # Map over each inner character-list of the (implicit) input-list:
 D     #  Duplicate the current character-list
  ðK   #  Remove all spaces from the copy
    k  #  Get the first 0-based index of each of these characters in the list
}ß     # After the map: pop and push the flattened minimum
  ð×   # Convert it to a string with that many spaces
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
↵ƛðv≠TgI;g
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLihrXGm8OwduKJoFRnSTtnIiwicSIsIlwiICAgSm9lIFxcbiAgIEJydWhcXG4gICAgIFBpcGlzXFxuICAgICAgXCIiXQ==)

A port of the jelly answer. 8 bytes with the `g` flag.

### Explained

```
↵ƛðv≠TgI;g
↵ƛ          # For each item n in the input split on newlines:
  ðv≠       #   Is each character not a space?
     Tg     #   Smallest index where ^ is truthy. Returns an empty list if all spaces. 
       I    #   Push that many spaces or two empty lists if it's all spaces.
        ;g  #   Return the smallest item of that.
```

Comment: There no longer is "the" Jelly answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

```javascript
s=>(s.match(/^ *(?=\S)/gm)||[""]).sort()[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU69DoIwEN55iouLdyYWdlPdHBx0YERNCBYsqS32qoHEd0fAn2@77/fq/Jlz4XUTltZdVF/KnuUaWdzyUFwxPsMCN/KYUlzd6PXKZrMTCXY@IGXJqWeQ4NX9ob3CeclzEl7ll602Ku1sgQmJ4NLgta2QVlHhLDujhHEV7tLDXvAk6bLDEpmIeoDRE6AdepFAriMY0AlujB4mpwtgeK5B/qkjWBhlq3D9En9j7bT9xqJP92@/pTc)

Or **40 bytes** by using optional chaining, as suggested by the OP:

```javascript
s=>s.match(/^ *(?=\S)/gm)?.sort()[0]||''
```

(doesn't work on TIO)

Comment: ... why did I not think of this?

Comment: With the optional chaining syntax `?.`, you could save 3 bytes.  `s=>s.match(/^ *(?=\S)/gm)?.sort()[0]||''`

Comment: Thank you for accepting this answer, but I'd suggest to un-accept it. We usually do not accept any answer at all on Code Golf -- or there should be a delay of at least one week or so before doing so.

Comment: Why need you `||[""]` if OP's first example don't handle empty?

Comment: Astute of you to replace the `(?=\S)` with `(?!$)`, but that [saves you 7 bytes](https://tio.run/##PU69DoIwEN55ijMx4c7E6m7QzcFBB0ajCYGCJaXFXjXw9FhQ/Lb7fq/O3hnnTrV@bWwhhzIZONkjiybz@QM3d1jhYbGkTdUQCbbOI123t4EhASefL@UkxiXHJJzMiqPSMu1NjlsS3qbeKVMh7aLcGrZaCm0rPKWXs@BJUmWPJTIRDQCjx0MXepEg2UcQ0AtutQqT0wUQvmqRZ3UECy1N5R8/4m@srTIhFn175@2OPg), not just 1, since the `||[""]` is now serving no purpose.

Comment: But alternatively for one extra byte (total **37**) you could [throw on empty](https://tio.run/##VY09C8IwFEX3/opueU8w7S7RSQcHC83oB4SY1EjbaF4UivS3R1pcvHDhwD1w7@qtSAf3iMveX02yIpFYA/FORX2D4pIvYCNOEoumQ@TkQwQ8ludEuciDeb5cMMAsMeTBqOvOtUYOvYYSefQyBtc3gKsshuGjfU@@Nbz1DexldeA0z84OYIEQcdTT55/HtnVd1QzHlP@STc1m/AI).

Comment: @Deadcode Actually, `(?!$)` is wrong as it would for instance return a single space on a line consisting of 2 spaces. (And yes, the `||[""]` stuff could probably be removed, but this is unrelated to the regex optimization.)

Comment: Oh, good point. FWIW, I was a bit confused because I only saw @l4m2's second reply (my eyes skipped over the reply above it), and I thought *you* got the idea for the `(?!$)` from the `||[""]` suggestion. In any case, you *could* get -2 bytes by changing `||[""]` to `||[]` to return `undefined` (instead of empty string) for any input containing no lines that are not pure whitespace. That could be interpreted as returning "nullish or the empty string" as per OP's instructions.

Comment: @Deadcode yeah, I addressed the "only whitespace" case after this answer (and my revision) were written.  I made a spur of the moment decision to accept nullish values.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 16 bytes

```
G`\S
O^`.+
!`^ +
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYy7CoAgGIV3n@K0KcH/BrU2NrRGKCFlmEY61NPbvW8711VH41RKlWwbVneScpbJDnlKQO9diNhQgAsUJcPJTmGxJnJxK4BmtfDwpReBrHZDHF/jL07euHfGnm9vNVk/8E0c) Explanation:

```
G`\S
```

Discard lines that only consist of whitespace.

```
O^`.+
```

Sort them in reverse order, so the line with the least space sorts first.

```
!`^ +
```

Output the leading spaces.

If just the count of leading spaces suffices, then for 14 bytes:

```
G`\S
O^`.+
\G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYy7CoAgGIV3n@KMSvC/ga2ODa0RSUgZppEO9fR279vOdTXJep2z6pqaVW1HBWsUcgb64GPCBgkuIEuGk53i4mzi4lYAzXrh8UsvIjnjhzS@xl@cgvXvjD3fwRlyYeCbOAA) Explanation: The last stage `\G`  counts consecutive spaces at the start of the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 39 bytes

```
lambda l:max(l)[:-len(max(l).lstrip())]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PU7LCsIwELz3K5Zc3CDNWQr1R9RD1D4i2yQ0EVrwT7wURC9-kX9jahrnsszs7M7cX3b0rdHToy73z6uv881nRbI7niVQ0ckBie-KnCqNkQhyvlcWOT8s9rftlfZYI2MM4GS08zBACcih3GYQMApnSfkg_CiA6KRFl9YznAgRjW8XgSfjxSiNkSXvnGCoEmQaHHgIjd9J6cqFWrAGdmM8-7cKJyypsfI0xfkF)

Takes input as a list of lines, per [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095).

Uses [Unrelated String's observation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242847) that the lexicographically greatest line will be the one with the least leading whitespace. This means the input must not contain unprintables other than newline.

Comment: I don't think we can assume that characters less than spaces will never appear. You should confirm that before using it in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>50</s> <s>62</s> <s>60</s> 57 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
sub("^( *).*","\\1",sort(sub(" *$","",readLines()),T)[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCsIwEETv@Ypl8bAbQqAfUL/AozerUDXUSExKNkL9@lhrdW4zb2ZyrfI8E54INFuNBruuQSMpF1oA6M0cosmuv@58dELMZs@H5sgV4JKiFJigBWJotwpmvayMwRfixQHYRz@S/OhHYoOLQ7mtwb94Tz6uM/X9TsHZkAaaWKn6Bg)

Comment: Two variants of -2 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBDsIgFET3nOKHuPifEJIeoJ7ApTtbk6oEMQgNH5N6eqyKzm7mzUyu1fHjhPKIoMgoqeUwdFJzygUbAbVZY6mznS47Hy0jkd7ToRupApxT5AIL9IAE/VbAqqfhOfiC9HEA5j7NyD/6FptgoyvXFvyLt@Rjm4nvdwrWhORwISHqCw "R – Try It Online") or [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxLDsIgEIb3nGJCXMyQhsS1wRO4dNdHWpUgBqHpYFJPj1Wr3@5/TqX0dW8cP0472SEo0krWsmm2srIBOU0ZZQdqs5iymuxwOfhoGamtjkRtATinyBlmMIAEZi9g4al5DD4jfRSAvg8j8i99wzrY6PJ1Nf7FW/JxnYnvdwpWh@RwJiHKCw "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk - Ah!  ```sort(,decreasing=T)```!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>9</s> <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

*Thanks to Jonathan Allan for bug-spotting (both versions)*

```
←T↑o¬wTfw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fYKWuBESPmhoPbfv/qG1CyKO2ifmH1pSHpJX///9fQSE5P6@4RKFCwVZBQ1PB1o5LAQgq9YoLcjJLNDTBPAUFvdzEAo1imCwIFOvlpOall2RABeAKs/Iz86DauCBm5@ek6uXkp2tUaHIBAA)

Takes a list of lines, removes all-space lines (`fw`), transposes (`T`), keeps longest prefix of all spaces (`↑o¬w`), transposes back again (`T`), and output first element (`←`).

---

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>7</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
↑=' →Ofw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fYKWuBESPmhoPbfv/qG2irbrCo7ZJ/mnl////V1BIzs8rLlGoULBV0NBUsLXjUgCCSr3igpzMEg1NME9BQS83sUCjGCYLAsV6Oal56SUZUAG4wqz8zDyoNi6I2fk5qXo5@ekaFZpcAA)

Uses [Unrelated string's lexicographic sorting approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242847/95126):
Takes a list of lines, removes all-space lines (`fw`), sorts (`O`), keeps last element (`→`), and keeps the longest prefix of spaces (`↑='` ).

Comment: You're right.  Drat.  Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```hs
fst.minimum.filter((>[]).snd).map(span(==' '))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY47EsIwDER7n0IddoEPkBmnp6KgBApPsINAVjzIzITLY/IBXqXP7kpXL/dAVJNHhqaB3R60UUvnALmEh@8K6AgWCDmIUSrOuuOhPJD7M2xbWEsV3alGKTYhY3omG5Emu9bt8Wys8MXY5LOW7Fk7t4GNMbUCdANLgXG6pg24VsHEy0omLNMjsLAaf9sZsRS4L9fv4C@8Dchfm1qzBwqWhl6P5t1F8r3UbZfzBw)

Nothing special here, it's a very standard approach, just with less whitespace. A more presentable version:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = interact (f . lines)

f :: [String] -> String
f = fst                      -- extract it from the tuple
  . minimum                  -- find the shortest leading whitespace (tuples are sorted by first element)
  . filter ((> []) . snd)   -- remove any tuples for which 'everything else' is empty
  . map (span (== ' '))      -- split each line into tuples of (leading whitespace, everything else)
```

Since `minimum` is a partial function, it will raise an exception if given input that consists only of whitespace. From my perusal of the rules, I'm under the impression that this is acceptable; but I'm fairly new here so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: [36?](https://tio.run/##ZY4/D4IwEMX3forbvA7U3Vh2JwdH4tBgC6ftQWhJNMbPjhXQxTfdn997ea2JN@v9FAwx7HZwOAJKMW8aiJMdTJ0AHSjwxDZKIdyHq05pIG7OUJSwjMJpF5MKxBTGoBz5bEbc6uosVeSLVMH0GHvDqPUGNjJHPYvpy49cj8PwwP3@H5yK1wRQdxwT3HMvlKBLAVkPFXtPKVeGWYv1@/0oKm@5Se16@IHXjni1iSW781b5rsG7fAM)

Comment: ...actually, I have no idea where that `<<` is coming from, so maybe [this](https://tio.run/##XYyxDsIwEEP3fMVtvQwNe6V0Z2JgLB1OJYETyalK0gEhvj0UKiSEF9vSs6@Uby6EGokFug72B0CtPs0CS3GJpgLowUBgcVkr5d/ccCyJ5TJC28MWlbc@FxNZOC7ReA7rGHFnh1GbLGdtIs2YZxK0toFGr1ePtn75RaYlpTv2/Q942sDaPiv8S6nNiV4) is preferable

Comment: @UnrelatedString I can't get that to typecheck :( My experience with Haskell on TIO is that it's a little bit contrived; the actual part where I count the bytes is a comment. The real code being executed is in the header. (Open to other suggestions, though.) So your TIO links are basically running my code :)

Comment: ...didn't quite notice that :|
For future reference [this](https://tio.run/##PY69DsIwDIT3PIU3kqFhR0p3JgZGYIhK0hocN8JBgpcnFFr4Jv/cnT14uQaimjwybDaw3YE26ts5QC7h5rsCOoIFQg5ilIof3WFfbsj9CZoW5lJFd6xRik3ImO7JRqTJrvXaHU7GCp@NTT5ryZ61cytYGVMrQDeyFHhM57QB1yqYeFrJhGX6BL7Mxt/2g1gK3JdhGfyFlxF5sak5e6Rgaez1w7y6SL6X2nQ5vwE) is how Haskell answers are usually done

Comment: @UnrelatedString Ah, ok. Thanks a lot! That's so much better.

Comment: I’m on my phone so I can’t test, but could this be implemented as the following? `minimum.filter(>[]).map(takeWhile(==’ ‘)` (note the smart quotes - I can’t seem to figure out how to be rid of them). At the very least you should be able to use `>` in lieu of `/=`. Also with the use of both filter and map a list comprehension might be worth the additional overhead.

Comment: @cole I think that doesn't treat whitespace-only lines correctly (for example, in the original example, a line with only one space would cause the program to incorrectly return one space only when it should return 2 spaces). `>` over `/=` is neat, thanks :)

Comment: I tried to mess with list comps, but I couldn't find a way to shorten it myself, mainly because of two reasons: (1) for a list comp, I think the list has to be bound to a variable which necessitates a lambda; (2) the filter and map are the wrong way round. Like, if we were doing `map g . filter f` then we could do `\xs -> [g x | x <- xs, f x]`; but `filter f . map g` becomes something like `\xs -> [g x | x <- xs, f (g x)]` where `g` has to be spelt out twice. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 39 bytes

```javascript
s=>/( *)\S(.|\s+(\1|$))*$|$/.exec(s)[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k5fQ0FLMyZYQ68mplhbI8awRkVTU0ulRkVfL7UiNVmjWDPaMPZ/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrqGV7C/n15xSVFmXnpmWqVGmoa6gkJiTF5SUmKiuqamJhcRahUUSFNNgvokIABqIUotEACVkqQD5Bqwyv8A)

Return `undefined` if no line

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

```javascript
s=>/( *)\S(.|\s+(\1|$))*$/.exec(s)[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc6xDoIwFIXhnafoQNJ7MZbwALi5OEgCo3UotSCGtIY2RiI8ey2bTuKZvz85N/EQVg7d3W21uSjf5N7muxRIgrwCNnG7AZ5NMWISp0w9lQSLp@zspdHW9Ir1poVDVRyZdUOn264ZoQFKiOC6roWgiBitsIT8p//wdVhIVtmwQD8LN4yvn9XyaNGzFE5evzzdl2VRUpwj/wY)

Throw if no line

Comment: OP said to [return nullish or the empty string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242833/capture-the-longest-leading-whitespace-substring-from-lines/242836?noredirect=1#comment547027_242833) and I would not interpret throwing to count as that... But you can return `undefined` for only [+2 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k5fQ0FLMyZYQ68mplhbI8awRkVTU0ulRkVfL7UiNVmjWDPaMPZ/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrqGV7C/n15xSVFmXnpmWqVGmoa6gkJiTF5SUmKiuqamJhcRahUUSFNNgvokIABqIUotEACVkqQD5Bqwyv8A).

Comment: Also I'd like to note that this is a pure-regex solution and thus could also be answered in the language "**Regex (ECMAScript)**". I was going to do so, but I can't think of any solution shorter than yours.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-r`, 15 bytes

```lisp
@SS Ks~Y#||_FIg
```

Takes input from stdin; prints a string of spaces (with a trailing newline) to stdout. Outputs nothing if the input contains only whitespace. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbpFS7IKlpSVpuhbrHYKDFbyL6yKVa2ri3TzTIaJQyQU3MxUUkvPziksUKhRsFTQ0FWztuBSAoFKvuCAns0RDE8xTUNDLTSzQKIbJgkCxXk5qXnpJBlQArjArPzMPpI0LYnB-TqpeTn66RoUmxEYA)

#### Explanation

The `-r` flag reads all of stdin and stores it as a list of lines in `g`. Then:

```lisp
@SS Ks~Y#||_FIg
            FIg  ; Filter g on this function:
         ||      ;   Strip whitespace from
           _     ;   each line
        #        ;   and get the length of what remains
       Y         ; Yank the result (used here just to manipulate precedence)
      ~          ; Get first match of this regex in (each line of) the above:
     s           ;   Preset variable: space
    K            ;   Kleene star (results in this regex: ` *`)
 SS              ; Sort in lexicographic order (in this case, shortest first)
@                ; Get the first element
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>48</s> 58 bytes

<sup>Revised to return *N* spaces instead of just the value of *N*.</sup>

```
=LET(t,TRIM(A:A),REPT(" ",MIN(IF(t="","",FIND(t,A:A)))-1))
```

Trim the leading and trailing white space from each line then find the position what's left in the original line, ignoring those lines that are empty once they're trimmed. Find the minimum of those positions minus 1. Return a space repeated that many times.

[image: Screenshot]

<sup>Screenshot shows formula returning repeated pipes instead of spaces so you can see the results.</sup>

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, it's been corrected now.

Comment: Lol, I had not considered Excel as a language.  Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι× ∨⌊ΦＥυ⌕Ｅ⪪ι ¬λ⁰⊕ι⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU1BboNADLzzCisnWyIod5QcI@WQNFL6AURW4MjrRaxp6Ou3C6WdgzUzHo/bvhnb0EhK757FAV50mOxhI2uHRHCfYo9TCUx1cc@m4Sd7F3EHuxI@Rryysp88nlnMZdkMS/rM@lz5YxA25BJynkq4BUOhTA7LuGg7Ou/U3BOZNpvqlADaoNFghiMgwfFUQMZ3Fdc2WhVA5fOD@LddECtx2lm/Gf/BV2Ddzorf7iCuktDhTEXaf8kP) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input by default as a list of newline-terminated strings, so if you want to provide an empty string as part of the input you'll have to encode it as a JSON list instead. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Input the string.

```
× ∨⌊ΦＥυ⌕Ｅ⪪ι ¬λ⁰⊕ι⁰
```

Split each line on spaces and find the index of the first non-space character, but filter out those lines that only have spaces, and then take the minimum number of spaces, or 0 if all lines only have spaces, and repeat a space that many times.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I hadn't accounted for the edge case when all the input lines only contain spaces, in which case I'm trying to repeat a string by the minimum of an empty list, which doesn't work.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sometimes I wish the sum or minimum of an empty list would be zero like it is in Jelly... at least for sum I have a workaround by using base 1 conversion instead, which is only 1 byte longer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 29 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.map{_1[/^ +/]}.sort[0]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhZ7de0SqxP1chMLquMNo_XjFLT1Y2v1ivOLSqINYmshalYWKLhFOwa5u8VC-Atu5igoJOfnFZcoVCjYKmhoKtjacSkAQaVecUFOZomGJpinoAAyVqMYJgsCxXo5qXnpJRlQAbjCrPzMPKg2LojZ-Tmpejn56RoVmhBLAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 23 bytes

```
t]:nzm{Jt[.-}saq<]qesIE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@T978k1iqvKrfaqyRaT7e2OLHQJrYwtdjT9f9/BSDgUlBIzk9JhVIA)

```
t]:nz  # Filter null/wspc lines
m{     # Map
 J     # Dup
 t[    # Trim left
 .-    # String Difference
}      -- Diff pre/post trim
sa     # non-destructive Length
q<]    # If non-zero length find max
qes    # Else Empty Block -> Empty string
IE     # If Else
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan Darn, missed that element. This should work now.

Comment: TIO version seems to output the longest *of all* whitespace prefixes, not the longest *present in every line* (which, confusingly, is the shortest...) [try it](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@T9z@3uiTWqyRaT7fWLvb/f4VELgUFBRBOTAQA)

Comment: In my haste, I'd completely misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 38 bytes

```perl
print[sort map/^ +/g,grep/\S/,<>]->[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RUy7DsIgFN37FScuhVjBxamWn3Bsa2IMQQxyCTDUr6/U@jjTeQcd3WEO0fpcb@p2ZX2imPG4BHnGVprGRB3kcJLNUY071e/Huf0vgCv5lDGhA@PoVIWCp0jB2cz4WwGivLH0TRck4bQ3@fYxfsU7WV9m1fpLTgtHhk38BQ)

Answer (score 0):

### [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 51 bytes

```
"\\n[\\s]*".r.findAllIn("\n"+y).map(_.length).min-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZA9SwQxEIZ7f8VLqkQxYHuwwpUHd5WFhRGJu7lcjjgJOyl28fzta/aw0BULxSkG5uudZ4ZbG@2Uno@uLdjZQHBDcdQx1jnj9QLo3B4xkXdcts52gfz9IRTH2bZOjivclb7m1AobKmgmYQw9GMOPl0L3eh@oW8e4ISkMiatR6Reb5ZOOjnw51CjQ9c0E5KpRIskfF1UQQAhxAtpEXDCggVRobs@VaqfZjZpzDEWqL1ngvJaX3bPxB8ui8E3gmAItZD8FM1OKTsfk5aAqp@b6lryzvQ@k5rHfXPifxH9iEaL2vU3v)

**Explanation:**

```
"\\n[\\s]*".r                   // regex to find newlines and all whitespaces after
           .findAllIn(          // iterator of all matches in the given string
                      "\n"+y)   // add a newline to the front to count first line
           .map(_.length).min   // find the shortest match
           -1                   // subtract one since lengths include the newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 28 bytes

```ruby
:*&(~:[]&/^ */)|:sort|:first
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWe6y01DTqrKJj1fTjFLT0NWusivOLSmqs0jKLiksgStYVKLhFOwa5u-mV5McnxkIEF9zMUVBIzs8rLlGoULBV0NBUsLXjUgCCSr3igpzMEg1NME9BQS83sUCjGCYLAsV6Oal56SUZUAG4wqz8zDyoNi6I2fk5qXo5-ekaFZoQSwE)

### Explanation

```ruby
:* & (           # Map lines with...
   ~:[] & /^ */  #   Get part that matches /^ */
) |              # then
:sort | :first   # sort, then get the first
```